# Using Map Kit how can I find my location?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, mapkit

I need to display my current position in Map Kit, how can I do this ?

```
self.map.showsUserLocation = TRUE;
```

is not showing my location instead a point somewhere else in the map? I need to find the location from where I am accessing the application. 
 Please help me in this..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use location manager for getting your current location. And then get the lat long value and create a annonation and display on map. If you use map.showsUserLocation = TRUE; it will show your current location in actual device.

Note - In simulator map kit shows apple's head quarter location somewhere in Cupertino - I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Thanks Rahul......u are right... i ve used the location manager and I got my location

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{



int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
int minutes = decimal * 60;
double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",degrees, minutes, seconds];                   
latLabel.text = lat;
degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
minutes = decimal * 60;
seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                   degrees, minutes, seconds];
longLabel.text = longt;
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
region.center.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
region.center.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
[mapView setDelegate:self];
}
```